# What kind of stitch is this?

Tags: sewing, sewing-machine

[image]

I wanted to know what kind of stitch is shown in this picture. Can I make it with a brother sewing machine cs6000i?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I didn’t had a chance to reply because my internet wasn’t working!

Comment: One friend told me that maybe it’s a overlook stitch too ! I want to make dog bandana

Answer (score 5):

It is most likely either an [overlock stitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=overlock%20stitch) or a [serger stitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=serger%20stitch). These are used to finish edges to prevent fraying and give a professional appearance to a sewn item.

> The overlock stitch is a combination of a straight stitch and a
>   zigzag. It sews backwards and forwards in a straight line, but between
>   every set of straight stitches, it sews a zigzag. If done correctly,
>   this resembles serging, which is how most store-bought clothes are
>   sewn. (*[Yesterday's Thimble](http://yesterdaysthimble.com/articles/basics-overlock-stitch/)*)

And it looks like [there are a few different overlock stitches on the Brother CS6000i](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3MTAL93aco)! To get that very compressed look as in your example picture, you would want the stitch length to be pretty short in comparison to the width. As always, experiment with a few sample pieces of fabric before you put your final piece through!

Comment: Also, I want that sewing machine. #jealous ;)

Answer (score 2):

I personally think this is an overlock stitch, however, I may be wrong!

The latter of this question I can answer though... Yes, the Brother CS6000i does allow an overlock stitch. I own a Brother CS6000i myself and can confirm this.

If you already know about the Brother CS6000i then you can ignore this part, but there is a review of it [here](https://www.quiltedsewing.com/best-sewing-machine-for-quilting/brother-cs6000i-review/) (unfortunately it does not seem to mention the different types of stitches) but it gives a decent insight into the Brother CS6000i. Anyway I hope I helped in some form or another, I am not an expert in sewing (Still learning :P)

Comment: All this information was already covered in the earlier answer. Do you have any other additions that weren't included there?

Comment: I gave an insight from my personal experiences which was not included in the previous comment? Some times people like reassurance when it is an indefinitive answer?